# My pokemon go eggs are not hatching

Tags: pokemon-go

I walk a lot and have Pokemon go opened, but my egg wont progress even 0.1 point when I walk enough to hatch a 5k egg.I have tried resetting my phone and have tried other tricks but with no fixing it.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! When you say you walk a lot, do you go outside and walk around a neighborhood/park or do you use a treadmill or something similar? If the latter, the first thing to check would be if you have Adventure Sync enabled

Comment: Adding to this, you should also check if an egg is placed inside an incubator

Comment: Make sure to allow location tracking on PoGo app

Answer (score 3):

You have to put eggs in an incubator to hatch them. From the egg screen, tap on an egg, and you should get a prompt with an "incubate" button.